# Javascript first argument gets ignored in nested functions with spread arguments

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I have this really simple variadic function that cycle through its arguments and adds a string "Transformed" to them.

```js
function Transform(...children) {
    return children.map(child=> child + " Transformed")
}
document.write(
    Transform(
       Transform(" test1", " test2"), //only test2 gets double transformed
       Transform(" test3") //here the first argument gets double transformed though
   )
)
```

For some strange reason when nesting them if I have only 1 argument it acts as expected but if I have more than one it won't affect the first argument.

How can I make the function add the string `Transformed` onto the end of all of the arguments? (You can see that `test1` does not have two `Transformed` after it, but `test2` and `test3` do).

Comment: If you want to flatten all arrays passed in, then you could just do `return children.flat().map(child=> child + " Transformed")`.

Comment: Yep I know about this but I was trying to avoid that since I noticed that array flattening in general is not really good for the performance

Comment: I personally would worry about that only if I'd done a performance test and found this was a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-spread the array out when you call the function as well (look at the arguments to the outer `Transform`):

```js
function Transform(...children) {
    return children.map(child=> child + " Transformed")
}
document.write(
    Transform(
       ...Transform(" test1", " test2"), //only test2 gets double transformed
       ...Transform(" test3") //here the first argument gets double transformed though
   )
)
```

If you want the function to handle both cases, then simply check whether each element is an array or not, and if the element is an array then handle it with `Transform` as well:

```js
function Transform(...children) {
    return children.map(child => Array.isArray(child) ? Transform(...child) : child + " Transformed");
}
document.write(
    Transform(
       Transform(" test1", " test2"), //only test2 gets double transformed
       Transform(" test3") //here the first argument gets double transformed though
   )
)
```

Slightly more verbose version:

```js
function Transform(...children) {
    return children.map(child => {
      if (Array.isArray(child)) return Transform(...child)
      else return child + " Transformed";
    });
}
document.write(
    Transform(
       Transform(" test1", " test2"), //only test2 gets double transformed
       Transform(" test3") //here the first argument gets double transformed though
   )
)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, I was just realizing that but I'm still wondering if there's a nicer way to do this editing the Transform function (like double spreading or more precisely nested spreading of multi dimensional array). This way my end user doesn't have to worry about spreading anymore

Comment: Edited that @math now the Transform function itself will handle both arrays and strings appropriately.

Comment: Thank you so much, exaclty what I was looking for to prevent the use of Array.flat which is really computing expensive

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance @math

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function Transform(...children) {
        return children.map(child=> child + " Transformed")
    }
    document.write(
        Transform(
        ...Transform("test1", "test2"), //only test2 gets double transformed
        Transform("test3") //here the first argument gets double transformed though
       )
    )
```

Ok I just found out that I had to spread the array returned by the inner Transform to make the transform applied on each element.
Do you think there is a better way to achieve the same result in a more intuitive way?